# Text not changing after rewarded video ad finished in Admob

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I am implementing Admob into my android unity game. For now I am testing the rewarded video ad.

I added a ui text and wanted the text to change after the rewarded video has finished playing.

But after the video finishes playing and I close the video, the text is not changing.

Here is my script:

```c#
private RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideo;
public Text text;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    RequestReward();
}

private void RequestReward()
{
    string adUnitId;
    adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";

    //rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(adUnitId);
    rewardBasedVideo = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    // Load the rewarded video ad with the request.
    this.rewardBasedVideo.LoadAd(request, adUnitId);
}

 public void DisplayRewardAd()
 {
     if (rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded())
         rewardBasedVideo.Show();
 }

 public void HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
     rewardBasedVideo.Show();
 }

 public void HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
 {
     RequestReward();
 }

 public void HandleRewardBasedVideoOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
     MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardBasedVideoOpened event received");
 }

 public void HandleRewardBasedVideoStarted(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
     MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardBasedVideoStarted event received");
 }

 public void HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
     text.text = "Done!";
 }

 public void HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded(object sender, Reward args)
 {
     text.text = "Done!";
 }

 public void HandleRewardBasedVideoLeftApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
     MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardBasedVideoLeftApplication event received");
 }

 private void OnEnable()
 {
     HandleRewardedAdEvents(true);
 }

 private void OnDisable()
 {
     HandleRewardedAdEvents(false);
 }
 void HandleRewardedAdEvents(bool subscribe)
{
    if (subscribe)
    {
        // Called when an ad request has successfully loaded.
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdLoaded += HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded;
        // Called when an ad request failed to load.
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad;
        // Called when an ad is shown.
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdOpening += HandleRewardBasedVideoOpened;
        // Called when the ad starts to play.
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdStarted += HandleRewardBasedVideoStarted;
        // Called when the user should be rewarded for watching a video.
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
        // Called when the ad is closed.
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdClosed += HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed;
        // Called when the ad click caused the user to leave the application.
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdLeavingApplication += HandleRewardBasedVideoLeftApplication;
    }
    else
    {
        // Called when an ad request has successfully loaded.
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdLoaded -= HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded;
        // Called when an ad request failed to load.
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdFailedToLoad -= HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad;
        // Called when an ad is shown.
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdOpening -= HandleRewardBasedVideoOpened;
        // Called when the ad starts to play.
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdStarted -= HandleRewardBasedVideoStarted;
        // Called when the user should be rewarded for watching a video.
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded -= HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
        // Called when the ad is closed.
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdClosed -= HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed;
        // Called when the ad click caused the user to leave the application.
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdLeavingApplication -= HandleRewardBasedVideoLeftApplication;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I forgot to add HandleRewardedAdEvents method to the question.

Comment: What is the content of `HandleRewardedAdEvents`?

Comment: I added it now. Sorry about that. I think derHugo's answer makes sense. I will try what he said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok now that you added the implementaion of `HandleRewardedAdEvents` I would change my answer and note that [`OnEnable` is executed **before** `Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) so to a moment when `rewardBasedVideo` probably doesn't exist yet.

So I would rather add the callbacks in

```c#
private void RequestReward()
{
    string adUnitId;
    adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";

    //rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(adUnitId);
    rewardBasedVideo = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

    // ADD THE CALLBACKS

    HandleRewardedAdEvents(true);

    // Load the rewarded video ad with the request.
    this.rewardBasedVideo.LoadAd(request, adUnitId);
}
```

Usually yes, you should remove any callback that isn't needed anymore. But in this case I would rather do it in

```c#
private void OnDestroy()
{
    HandleRewardedAdEvents(false);
}
```

Not every time in `OnEnable` and `OnDisable`.

And use

```c#
private void HandleRewardedAdEvents(bool subscribe)
{
    // NOTE that it is always secure to first remove callbacks
    // even if not added yet
    // this makes sure they are definitely only added once

    // Called when an ad request has successfully loaded.
    rewardBasedVideo.OnAdLoaded -= HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded;
    // Called when an ad request failed to load.
    rewardBasedVideo.OnAdFailedToLoad -= HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad;
    // Called when an ad is shown.
    rewardBasedVideo.OnAdOpening -= HandleRewardBasedVideoOpened;
    // Called when the ad starts to play.
    rewardBasedVideo.OnAdStarted -= HandleRewardBasedVideoStarted;
    // Called when the user should be rewarded for watching a video.
    rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded -= HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
    // Called when the ad is closed.
    rewardBasedVideo.OnAdClosed -= HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed;
    // Called when the ad click caused the user to leave the application.
    rewardBasedVideo.OnAdLeavingApplication -= HandleRewardBasedVideoLeftApplication;

    if (!subscribe) return;

    // Called when an ad request has successfully loaded.
    rewardBasedVideo.OnAdLoaded += HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded;
    // Called when an ad request failed to load.
    rewardBasedVideo.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad;
    // Called when an ad is shown.
    rewardBasedVideo.OnAdOpening += HandleRewardBasedVideoOpened;
    // Called when the ad starts to play.
    rewardBasedVideo.OnAdStarted += HandleRewardBasedVideoStarted;
    // Called when the user should be rewarded for watching a video.
    rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
    // Called when the ad is closed.
    rewardBasedVideo.OnAdClosed += HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed;
    // Called when the ad click caused the user to leave the application.
    rewardBasedVideo.OnAdLeavingApplication += HandleRewardBasedVideoLeftApplication;
}
```

Comment: I added the callbacks to the question. I will try what you said. Thanks